# Generate 5 digit random code which is not in the list

Tags: javascript

My requirement is to generate 5 digit unique code which is not in the list already.

For example if I have `[12345, 54321, 13245, 11234]`, I would like to generate `34522` etc.. I am using below code for it

```
function id(){
    var text = "", can = "12345";
    for( var i = 5; i--; text += can.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * can.length)));
    return text;
}

var list = [12345, 54321, 13245, 11234];
var generated;
while(!generated){
   var t = makeid();
      if(list.indexOf(t) == -1){
          generated = t;
      }
}
```

This works fine, but when list grows, this would take more time(?). Are there any other ways to write this mechanism.

Comment: If it's just numbers you can use a hash approach. `var seen={}`, then `if(!(x in seen)){seen[x]=1}`. That will be faster.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes that's true. But assuming list as an array there are many operations that I cant change. Sorry

Comment: You're missing the point, I mean use an object as cache, instead of calling `indexOf` on the array. Keep the cache in a closure.

Comment: @elclanrs Like `var obj = {}, for(var i = list.length; i--; obj[list[i]] = true)` and then `if(t in obj)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @elclanrs [said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25676477/1529630#comment-40127593), better use a hash approach

```
var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<list.length; ++i) { obj[list[i]] = true; }
```

and then check

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(t);
```

Better use `hasOwnProperty` and not `in` to avoid searching in the prototype chain.

---

However, you can simplify it using ES6 [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
var set = Set(list);
```

and then check

```
set.has(t)
```

Note not all browsers support it yet.

---

Be aware that `id` returns a string, but `list` is an array of numbers!

To fix that, convert the id to a number (e.g. with unary `+`), or use something like

```
function id() {
    var num = 0, len = 5;
    for(var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        num *= 10;
        num += Math.floor(Math.random() * len) + 1;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the same approach and made hash like below rather using for loop `JSON.parse('{"' + (list.split(',').join('":0,"')) + '":0}');`